# Simple malloc and free implementation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel

I am trying to implement a simple malloc and free. The buffer is a char array.
Each chunk's address is calculated using the size of the previous chunk.

```
#define BUFF_SZ 64

typedef struct {
    int sz;
    int used;
}blk_hdr;

char buff[BUFF_SZ];

blk_hdr *start,*end;

void init()
{
    start = buff;
    start->sz = BUFF_SZ - sizeof(blk_hdr);
    start->used = 0;
    end = &buff[BUFF_SZ];
}


blk_hdr* next_block(blk_hdr *curr)
{
    return (void*)(curr+1) + curr->sz;
}

void split(blk_hdr *curr,int sz)
{
    int old_sz;
    old_sz = curr->sz;

    curr->used = 1; // mark used
    curr->sz = sz;

    blk_hdr *next = (void*)(curr+1) + sz; // new block with remaining bytes
    next->sz = old_sz - sz - sizeof(blk_hdr);
    next->used = 0;
}

void* mm_malloc(int size)
{
    for(blk_hdr *i = start; i!=end; i = next_block(i))
    {
        if(i->sz >= size && i->used == 0)  // if big enough and free
        {
            split(i,size);
            return (void*)(i+1); // return address after header of current block
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void coalesce()
{
    blk_hdr *prev = NULL;
    blk_hdr *curr;
    for(curr = start; curr != end; curr = next_block(curr))
    {
        /* coalesce current free block with previous block if free */
        if(curr->used == 0 && prev && prev->used == 0)
            prev->sz += curr->sz + sizeof(blk_hdr);
        else
            prev = curr;
    } 
}
void mm_free(blk_hdr *curr)
{
    curr->used=0;  // mark free
    coalesce();
}

#define CONTAINER(offset) ((blk_hdr*)(offset) - 1)

int main()
{
    init();
    void *ptr1,*ptr2,*ptr3;
    ptr1 = mm_malloc(4);
    printf("block: %p\n",ptr1);
   
    ptr2 = mm_malloc(4);
    printf("block: %p\n",ptr2);

    ptr3 = mm_malloc(16);
    printf("block: %p\n",ptr3);

    mm_free(CONTAINER(ptr1));
    mm_free(CONTAINER(ptr2));
    mm_free(CONTAINER(ptr3));

    ptr1 = mm_malloc(10);
}
```

I have tested this and it works. The free call results in going through all the blocks and coalescing adjacent free blocks resulting in O(n) complexity.
I am looking for any corner cases that I may be missing and improvements while keeping the algorithm same.

Comment: Did you miss an include?  There's no declaration of `printf`.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes. updated the post

Comment: Please don’t edit the code after receiving a review. Readers should be able to see the same code the reviewers did.

Comment: If you’d like to update and receive reviews of the new version, that’s great: you can post it as a follow-up question.

Comment: Nice question, by the way. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Davislor Thank you!  Will keep your points in mind

Answer (score 6):

*This review pertains more to the language than the allocator.*

**Use `size_t` for sizes, cardinalities, or ordinal numbers:**

```
typedef struct {
    int sz;
    int used;
} blk_hdr;
```

Can `sz` and `used` ever be negative? If not, change their types to `size_t`. Or if `used` is supposed to denote the availability of a chunk, consider changing its type to `bool` from `stdbool.h`.

**Missing header file:**

The code is missing the inclusion of `stdio.h`.

**Enable more compiler warnings:**

`mm_malloc()` is returning an `int` in case of a failure without a cast. There is no implicit conversion from a `void *` to an `int`.

**Check the return values of library/system calls:**

```
init();
    // ??
    ptr1 = mm_malloc(4);
    printf("block: %p\n",ptr1);
    
    // ??
    ptr2 = mm_malloc(4);
    ...
```

There is no point in returning an error code if you're not going to check for it.

**Arithmetic on a `void *` is illegal in C:**

```
blk_hdr *next = (void*)(curr+1) + sz;
```

The cast operator trumps binary addition according to the precedence table. In cases where the compiler provides extensions, it's still a good idea to adhere to the C standard to ensure code portability and readability.

**Redundant casts:**

There is an implicit conversion to and from a `void *` in C. Most of the casts in your code are redundant.

**If the function does not take any parameters, it should be defined with the keyword `void` inside the parenthesis:**

```
void init()
```

This takes an unspecified number of arguments, not zero. (Prior to C23)

Change it to:

```
void init(void)
```

**Incompatible pointer type assignments:**.

In the `init()` function, there are assignments to `start` and `end` pointers that result in incompatible pointer types. Specifically, `start` and `end` are declared as `blk_hdr *` pointers, but they are being assigned values of type `char *`.

**Others:**

- Consider using `true` and `false` from `stdbool.h` to denote a binary state:

  ```
  // curr->used = 1; // mark used
  curr->used = true;
  ```
- Use an automatic code formatter like GNU indent to format the code.